# Computing KL divergence between Poisson and Normal?

Tags: probability-theory, normal-distribution, machine-learning, poisson-distribution, information-theory

I understand that KL divergence between two distributions is only defined when the two distributions are defined on the exact same probability space. This means that one cannot straight up compute KL divergence between a discrete and a continuous distribution.

*However, is there a handy (or well-understood) way of computing the KL divergence between a Poisson and a Normal distribution?*

I would generally think of discretizing the continuous distribution and then numerically computing the KL divergence between the two. But I'm wondering for the specific case of Poisson and Normal, if there's a clean way to do that.

Comment: Try a different metric on distributions, like transportation distance.

Comment: I can unfortunately not do that since I'm computing KL as part of a variational inference procedure.

Comment: I'm thinking that perhaps the right way is the opposite of what I suggested in the post -- which is to dequantize the discrete (Poisson) distribution and measure KL on a continuous space. The non-rigorous justification I have in mind is that a discrete quantity of interest that, for instance the Poisson is modeling, is perhaps better thought off as observations reflecting a continuous latent quantity. This is bordering mathematics and philosophy but -- can I generally make such assumption? Dequantize using a continuous latent variable?